# Can you *donate* to a non-charitable cause?

Tags: word-choice, connotation

I just had someone insist that a *donation* can only be to a charitable cause or organization; otherwise, the word *contribution* should be used. When I objected to "contribution" on the grounds that it sounds like what you send to your favorite politician, he suggested *offering*. But that's not any better - I've only really seen it used in church.

Is he right that *donation* implies *charity*? If yes, what's a good alternative?

Comment: I donate myself to Stack Exchange. Yet I doubt it is a charity - not enough giving: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-gives-back-2010/ ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A *donation* is a voluntary gift or contribution for a specific cause.

That cause does not have to be a charity, a political donation is still a donation, it is a gift for a fund of some description.  There may be restriction on the use from an accountancy perspective in certain parts of the world, but not from a linguistic perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Donation comes from latin, dono, -are. to give, or donum, doni, n., gift (in general). Thus, I doubt it's restricted to charities.

Comment: Careful: the etymology of a word sometimes has nothing to do with its current *definition*, nevermind *connotation*.

Comment: good point. I defer to Orbling's comment above. thanks:-)

Answer (score 2):

Tax expert here.  At least in America, "donation" and "charity" are linked because *only charities* get favorable tax treatment. They don't pay taxes, and **your donation is tax deductible**. You donate $100 and your taxes drop by $40, net cost to you is $60.  So it rankles Americans to call it a "donation" when they can't take a tax deduction.

Contrast with the UK, where there is no tax advantage to donations, charity or not.  However the government will *match* your gift to a charity, amplifying the power of your gift.  You donate $60 and the government donates another $40.  It's the same effect but a very different mechanism, leading to different thinking.